# Wordpress logo image in header.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom theme in Wordpress, and currently I'm working on my `header.php` file. However, I'm unable to display my logo image. Here's the code for the same:

```
<body>

        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "five columns">
                <a href = "<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><img src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/sem.jpg" title = "<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

The `sem.jpg` image is stored inside the `img` folder inside my root project directory. However, the logo doesn't seem to be displayed on my webpage. I have also tried using images of other formats, but none of them seems to work. I have also called the `get_header()` function inside my `index.php`.

What seems to be wrong in my code?

Comment: Is your logo image inside `root/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME-NAME/img/sem.jpg` or `root/img/sem.jpg`?

Comment: `root/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME-NAME/img/sem.jpg`. The blog title and everything else is working just fine. It's just the logo image that isn't being displayed.

Comment: Can you view that image dirrectly in browser by writing it's url?

Comment: Try to right click your non-working image and find out where it's url is heading.

Comment: @Kyrbi Here's the url of my non-working image: `file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/getevangelized/img/sem.jpg` where `getevangelized` is the name of my theme.

Comment: When you right click that image and chosse Open in new tab, does that image work?

Comment: @Kyrbi Yes, the open does open inside a browser after I right-click and open it. Also, after I tried inspecting the image element on my web page, this is the URL of the image that is being generated: `src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/getevangelized/img/sem.jpg"`. When I tried opening this URL ina  browser, I get a `You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.` error. What does that mean?

Comment: I just answered your question, did it help?

Comment: @Kyrbi I didn't know how to use an FTP client, so I changed the permissions simply by right-clicking the project folder and changing its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seems a permissions problem.
You can set permission 777 to the logo image via command line, typyng:

```
   chmod 777 /path_to_your_file
```

or set using right click on the logo file, and change properties.

Comment: I read  your comment in the post above. 
The problem seems not the url but the permissions, Try to set permission 777 to the file.

Comment: How do I set about to do that? Sorry, this is the first time I'm trying to work with Wordpress and PHP.

Comment: if you are in linux os.
You can do in Terminal 
chmod 777 /path_to_your_file
so probably:
chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/getevangelized/img/sem.jpg‌

for php use this if is your template:
"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/sem.jpg"

Comment: Changed the permissions under the `Properties` section by right-clicking the project directory. The logo image is being displayed now. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime, if my answer helped you, mark it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't view your image because you have got set wrong permissions on your image. Open your FTP client, connect to your site and find your image, right click it and chosse Change file permissions and change them to 644.

File permissions should look like this:

http://s12.postimg.org/rxb25ziy5/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "five columns">

    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/sem.jpg"  alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?" />
 </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Enjoy..!!

Comment: i tried replacing my code with yours and this doesn't seem to work either. The title and everything else are being displayed just as intended, but the logo image doesn't.

Comment: Replay This in your Body `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: This is what the source code is when I tried inspecting the image elements: `src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/getevangelized/img/sem.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

user this wordpress [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-logo-plugin/installation/) 
it will help yo upload logo using wordpress admin and you can change any time with edit header.php file.
Use below function to print logo

> echo theme_logo();